# Wasm module compile error in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webassembly

In my extension I want to use my own WebAssembly module.

After loading my module (to `background.html`, or `popup.html`), I catch the compile error:

> CompileError: WebAssembly.compile(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder.

Are wasm modules not supported in Chrome Extensions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems from [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686369) that Chrome requires `script-src: 'unsafe-eval'` CSP directive be active for WebAssembly compilation. See [this discussion](https://github.com/WebAssembly/content-security-policy/issues/1) as to why this is the case, at least for now.

Chrome Extensions come with [default restrictions on CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy); that includes not allowing `unsafe-eval`. Some of the restrictions cannot be lifted; in this case, you *can* allow `unsafe-eval` by adding a manifest key:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

This should be enough to test if Wasm works in extensions. But heed this warning from documentation:

> However, we strongly recommend against doing this. These functions are notorious XSS attack vectors.

Instead of allowing `unsafe-eval` for your whole extension, you can sandbox code that requires it, using the following approach from the docs:

[Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval)

The gist of it is to create a separate page in your extension, where `unsafe-eval` is allowed but Chrome API access is disallowed; you then embed this page in your extension and communicate with it using [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: Chrome [implemented special policy 'wasm-eval'](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7041) exclusively for extensions to resolve this problem.

Comment: @MadRunner Please add that as a second answer (with a little explanation), I'd gladly upvote it.

Comment: Does this have a manifest v3 equivalent?

Comment: @f4z3k4s See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1173354

Comment: `'wasm-unsafe-eval'` can be used with Manifest V3.

Answer (score 14):

Chrome [implemented special policy 'wasm-eval'](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7041) exclusively for apps and extensions to resolve this problem. It is chrome-specific, but slowly moving into [CSP](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/pull/293) and [WebAssembly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/content-security-policy/issues/7) standards. Just replace `'unsafe-eval'` with `'wasm-eval'` in @Xan's solution.

Note though, this is still an attack vector and it's your responsibility to verify the source of executed assembly. See for example [uBlock's author thoughts](https://github.com/WebAssembly/content-security-policy/issues/7#issuecomment-441259729) on this policy.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me (ASP.NET Blazor client-side)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the 'unsafe-eval' and 'wasm-eval' provided by the other answers here but it didn't fix it. Turned out it's specific to the website. If I try it on Github, it doesn't work. But on reddit.com it works. Below is the error I'm seeing in Chrome developer mode. This is for Chrome extension made using Blazor NET6 with AOT. Hopefully someone finds this useful.

```
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder
window.Module.s.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
window.Module.s.instantiateWasm @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
createWasm @ dotnet.6.0.0.cnc7cl383g.js:1
(anonymous) @ dotnet.6.0.0.cnc7cl383g.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder
    at blazor.webassembly.js:1
    at async blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in typo-script on a TYPO3-system and  '`unsafe-eval`' or '`wasm-eval`' won't work. :-(

I defined it in the `.htaccess` and it works. :-)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin {linkToDomain}
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' blob: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-eval'  {other code ...} ; {other code ...} script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-eval' {other code ...};   object-src 'self' 'wasm-eval';{other code ...}"
</IfModule>
```

P.S. Safari makes problems. After adding a `site.manifest`, extending the Content-Security-policy for `default-src` in `TypoScript od TYPO3` and `.htaccess` it seems to work. (see above)

It seems to me, that every browser works different.