# CORS problem with Adblock eval on my website

Tags: eval, policy, adblock

when I activate adblock plus on my website functions like eval() are not allowed anymore, without adblock activated it works fine. Anyone know what I can do about it? Do I need to allow "adblock" to use those functions. I don't get it at all the whole CORS thing was always just ??? to me especially when third party extension can "break" my code because itself breaks anything?

So is there a fool-proofed version like add this line to .htaccess or in your php header. Because I tried some copy&paste line which should allow it but it never worked.

The other thing which is also blocked:

```
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder
```

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Comment: What makes you think CORS has anything to do with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763453/wasm-code-generation-disallowed-by-embedder-in-chrome seems related

Comment: because unsave_eval is a cors problem and i read that the wasm one is also a cors problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523118/wasm-module-compile-error-in-chrome-extension