# WebAssembly inside Chrome Extension in Sandbox with Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sandbox, content-security-policy, webassembly, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to get a library with WebAssembly running with manifest v3 in a Chrome extension.

I have a basic file (call it `sandbox.html`) which executes some JavaScript:

```js
if (typeof WebAssembly === "object" && typeof WebAssembly.instantiate === "function") {
    const module = new WebAssembly.Module(Uint8Array.of(0x0, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
}
```

This is embedded in a page with this tag:

```html
<iframe
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" 
    csp="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" src="sandbox.html">
</iframe>
```

I have not added `sandbox` or `content_security_policy` to my `manifest.json` because I require `allow-same-origin`, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291955/creating-sandbox-window-from-service-worker#comment122491003_69291955).

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523118/wasm-module-compile-error-in-chrome-extension) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763453/wasm-code-generation-disallowed-by-embedder-in-chrome), it's suggested that using `unsafe-eval` should be enough to make this run. However as far as I am aware, I am doing that but I still get this error.

(I believe I should be using `wasm-eval` over `unsafe-eval`; I have tried both and neither work. I have also tried including `content_security_policy` without `allow-same-origin` in my `manifest.json` but excluding the `sandbox` key.)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Per https://crbug.com/1173354#c19 it should work with content_security_policy.sandbox in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your reply - do you know if there's anywhere else I need to add the CSP apart from in manifest.json as you mentioned and the sandbox csp attribute, especially if the library I'm trying to use uses Workers? Ive tried putting the CSP in both places but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue :/